# How to use TypeScript's indexed access types with nullable nested types?

Tags: typescript, nullability

I'm trying to define a TypeScript type in terms of another type.

This works:

```
type Result = { data: { nestedData: { foo: string; bar: string } } };

type NestedData = Result['data']['nestedData'];
```

But, when the `data` property is nullable, this doesn't work:

```
type Result = { data: { nestedData: { foo: string; bar: string } } | null };

type NestedData = Result['data']['nestedData'];
```

and results in the error:

> ```
> Property 'nestedData' does not exist on type '{ nestedData: { foo: string; bar: string; }; } | null'.(2339)
> ```

How can I define my `NestedData` type in terms of `Result`, without duplicating any part of `Result`'s typings?

[**Demo on TypeScript Playground**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOBXANsKBeKBvKATAhsPgFzZQB2CwEuAIoSWQGYD2Lp8wATgJbkDmAbigAjfFw7c+-KAF85UAD4UUyOYIBQG0JCgA5KjXpEMsBCmABtAOQEi1gLo3KnIw0eCgA)

Edit: I'm getting my `NestedData` type from a codegen tool and I'm defining `NestedData` as a shorter type alias. In reality the typing is longer so I want to minimize repetition.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `NonNullable` to remove `null` (and `undefined`) from the union:

```js
type NestedData = NonNullable<Result['data']>['nestedData']
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOBXANsKBeKBvKATAhsPgFzZQB2CwEuAIoSWQGYD2Lp8wATgJbkDmAbigAjfFw7c+-KAF85UAD4UUyOYIBQG0JCgA5KjXpEM+luT2r8I5BAA8cJKgDaAcgJFXAXQB8bypxGDN4aQA)

Equivalently, but a bit more verbosely, you can use `Exclude`:

```js
type NestedData = Exclude<Result['data'], null>['nestedData']
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOBXANsKBeKBvKATAhsPgFzZQB2CwEuAIoSWQGYD2Lp8wATgJbkDmAbigAjfFw7c+-KAF85UAD4UUyOYIBQG0JCgA5KjXpEMUAKIAPAMbJEuCAB44SVAG0A5ASLuAugBoVZGQAPg9KTiMGXw0gA)

It makes sense to do it in one of these ways when you can't change your `Result` type for some reason. In other situations it would be more natural to define them this way round:

```js
type NestedData = { foo: string; bar: string }
type Result = { data: { nestedData: NestedData } | null }
```

Comment: "But in most situations it would be more natural to define them this way round:" Maybe yes, but I get my `NestedData` type from a codegen tool and I'm defining `NestedData` as a shorter type alias.

Comment: Yep, in that case it makes sense to do it that way round, and you'll want to use `Exclude`.

Comment: This works with optional fields too, e.g. you can use type `NestedData = Exclude<Result['data'], null | undefined>['nestedData']` if the original type is defined as `data?: ...`

Answer (score 2):

Generic util for getting nullable properties:

```js
type Result = {
    data: {
        nestedData: { foo: string; bar: string }
    } | null
};

type GetNullable<T, Prop extends keyof NonNullable<T>> = NonNullable<T>[Prop]

type NestedData = GetNullable<Result['data'], 'nestedData'>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShDOBXANsKBeKBvAUFfUAJgIbDEBc2eBNAdgsBIQCKkXZQBmA9t5fMABOAS1oBzANxQARsUH8hosVAC+1fCqgAfKLRTIcKiThyhIUAOIRgAOX3FpyCAB4AKgBooABUHcwUCAAPRlpCeCgAawgQbk4oG25aO2RkByc3AD4MjHjE5NTHF1cMgG0fPwBdEzNoGwYmVjIcq1t7Quc4JFQSgHISMh6Kzx76AQa2HoycIA)

Comment: Thanks, a very good answer as well! `NonNullable` is perhaps even cleaner than `Exclude<..., null>`.

Comment: I think you can basically get the type like this : `type NestedData = NonNullable<Result['data']>["nestedData"] `

Comment: @Eldar you are right, I just left second argument in order to use it not only with this data structure. It is more generic with two arguments